# extracting an tag at the same level of another tag in shell script

Tags: xml, bash, shell, scripting

Say i have the following XML:

```
<app-deployment>
    <name>gr1</name>
    <target>AdminServer</target>
    <module-type>ear</module-type>
    <source-path>/u01/app/wls1035_homes/wls1035_9999/grc864</source-path>
    <security-dd-model>DDOnly</security-dd-model>
    <staging-mode>stage</staging-mode>
</app-deployment>
<app-deployment>
    <name>gr2</name>
    <target>AdminServer</target>
    <module-type>ear</module-type>
    <source-path>/u01/app/wls1035_homes/wls1035_9999/grc864</source-path>
    <security-dd-model>DDOnly</security-dd-model>
    <staging-mode>nostage</staging-mode>
</app-deployment>  
<app-deployment>
    <name>gr3</name>
    <target>AdminServer</target>
    <module-type>ear</module-type>
    <source-path>/u01/app/wls1035_homes/wls1035_9999/grc864</source-path>
    <security-dd-model>DDOnly</security-dd-model>
</app-deployment>
```

how can i extract the value of the staging-mode tag, say for the app-deployment named gr2?

Comment: no perl solutions please, as i am limited to using only shell script solutions such as sed, awk, etc

Comment: and your xml will always be as cleanly formatted as your sample above?

Comment: yes, it an xml generated by another script, so formatting will always be the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many people (including myself), will tell you that it is a fools errand to parse xml with reg-ex based tools, and that you should use tools designed for xml parsing. Xpath should work for this, and xmlstarlet would be a package you could install and use quickly.

That said, given that you assume your data will always be well formed, it is pretty easy to make an awk script to search for 1 pattern, set a flag, look for another pattern, set a flag, etc. And when you have found the final target, cleanup the line to extract just the data you want.

```
set -- gr2
{ cat - <<-EOS
<app-deployment>
    <name>gr2</name>
    <target>AdminServer</target>
    <module-type>ear</module-type>
    <source-path>/u01/app/wls1035_homes/wls1035_9999/grc864</source-path>
    <security-dd-model>DDOnly</security-dd-model>
    <staging-mode>nostage</staging-mode>
</app-deployment>
EOS
} | awk '
    /[<]app-deployment/{a=1}
    a && /[<]name[>]'"$1"'/{n=1}
    a && n && /[<]staging-mode[>]/{
      sub(/[<]staging-mode[>]/,"", $0)
      sub(/[<]\/staging-mode[>]/,"",$0)
      print $0
      exit
    }
    #dbg { print "a=" a "\tn=" n }
  '
```

Output

```
       nostage
```

The `set -- gr3`  and `{ cat ... } |` are a testing harness, you would wrap this is a shell script i.e.

```
 cat printXMLarg.bash
 #!/bin/bash
   targ=$1; shift
   awk '
    /[<]app-deployment/{a=1}
    a && /[<]name[>]'"${targ}"'/{n=1}
    a && n && /[<]staging-mode[>]/{
      sub(/[<]staging-mode[>]/,"", $0)
      sub(/[<]\/staging-mode[>]/,"",$0)
      print $0
      exit
    }
    #dbg { print "a=" a "\tn=" n }
  ' "${@}"
```

and call like

```
  printXMLarg.bash gr3 *.xml
```

This 2nd part is untested. Let me know if you have problems with it.

I hope this helps

Comment: thanks so much. this works great. The reason i wanted to use sed or awk was that i don't know what type of packages will be available on the linux machines this script is going to be used on. So I  thought since awk and sed always will be there, it's the way to go in my case. Thank again for your answer.

Comment: is there any way to change the above script to return nothing when passing grc3 ( in the case of the example xml in my question) since it has no staging-mode tag? currently it returns nostage for some reason.

Comment: Fixed, I think. Let me know if otherwise. Good night.