# resetting a flag in awk

Tags: linux, shell, scripting, awk

I have the following function which uses awk:

```
getStageMode() {
targ=$1; shift
       mode=$(awk '
        /[<]app-deployment/{a=1}
        a && /[<]name[>]'"${targ}[<]"'/{n=1}
        a && n && /[<]staging-mode[>]/{ 
          sub(/[<]staging-mode[>]/,"", $0)
          sub(/[<]\/staging-mode[>]/,"",$0)
          print $0
          exit
        }
        {print "n=" n }
        ' "${@}")
echo $mode
}
```

I am having trouble resting the n flag after it's set to 1. where is the proper place to reset it?

Comment: What is the condition for resetting n?

Comment: related to http://stackoverflow.com/q/9269585/371250

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
/[<]\/app-deployment/{a=0; n=0}
```

So, you would have:

```
getStageMode() {
targ=$1; shift
   mode=$(awk '
    /[<]\/app-deployment/{a=0; n=0}
    /[<]app-deployment/{a=1}
    a && /[<]name[>]'"${targ}[<]"'/{n=1}
    a && n && /[<]staging-mode[>]/{ 
      sub(/[<]staging-mode[>]/,"", $0)
      sub(/[<]\/staging-mode[>]/,"",$0)
      print $0
      exit
    }
    {print "n=" n }
    ' "${@}")
echo $mode
}
```

*Explanation:*
OP has a generated file with XML nodes like:

```
<app-deployment>
    <name>gr2</name>
    <target>AdminServer</target>
    <module-type>ear</module-type>
    <source-path>/u01/app/wls1035_homes/wls1035_9999/grc864</source-path>
    <security-dd-model>DDOnly</security-dd-model>
    <staging-mode>nostage</staging-mode>
</app-deployment>  
<app-deployment>
    <name>gr3</name>
    <target>AdminServer</target>
    <module-type>ear</module-type>
    <source-path>/u01/app/wls1035_homes/wls1035_9999/grc864</source-path>
    <security-dd-model>DDOnly</security-dd-model>
</app-deployment>
```

The AWK script sets `a` when we are inside an `app-deployment` XML node, and `n` when that node has the `name` we are looking for. Since some nodes have no `staging-mode`, the original AWK, which didn't reset neither `a` nor `n`, could return the `staging-mode` for the following node. Resetting those variables when exiting a node should fix that issue.